# Destructuring or assign operator

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

How can I write the following using new ES6 features:

```
    this.currentPlayer = values.currentPlayer;
    this.gameOver = values.gameOver;
    this.inCheck = values.inCheck;
```

I believe I should either use destructuring operator or Object.assign function or both

Comment: Not everything is different in ES6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK there's no way to usefully simplify that code, unless those three fields are the only ones present in `values`.

If (and only if) that is the case, you can just use:

```
Object.assign(this, values);
```

There *is* a destructuring version, but IMHO it's not worth using because it's barely any shorter than individual explicit assignments:

```
({currentPlayer: this.currentPlayer,
  gameOver: this.gameOver,
  inCheck: this.inCheck} = values);
```